# C- Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

I am constantly getting "Segmentation fault (Core dumped)" error in the following c program. Please help me debug the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
int numcmp(const char *a,const char *b){
    if(atoi(a)==atoi(b)) return 0;
    return -1;
}
int isequal(char *a,char *b,int (*cmp)(const char *,const char *)){
    if(!cmp(a,b)) return 1;
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    if(argc!=3){
        puts("Usage: Compare two string alphabeticaly or numericaly");
        printf("Syntax: %s string1 string2\n",argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(isequal(argv[1],argv[2],isalpha(argv[1])?strcmp:numcmp))
        printf("%s and %s are equal\n",argv[1],argv[2]);
    else
        printf("%s and %s are not equal\n",argv[1],argv[2]);
}
```

Comment: Did you get any warnings when compiling your program? I would expect at least one, on the `isalpha(argv[1])?strcmp:numcmp` line.

Comment: Did you try to debug it yourself ?

Comment: no warning, program compiled successfully. Getting error while running the program

Comment: `isalpha(argv[1])` --> `isalpha(*argv[1])`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY But wouldn't that just check if the **first** characters is a letter?

Comment: I think not necessary to use such auxiliary functions if examining all the characters. It is better to find out whether or not rather be interpreted as a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isalpha` only works for `char`s, not whole strings. You could write a function for that:

```
/* 1 - only letters, 0 - other characters */
int str_isalpha(const char* str) {
    while (*str)
        if (!isalpha(*(str++)))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

and then use it appropriately. But actually, I don't see a reason for using `numcmp` here at all. Comparing `int`s and `const char*`s should yield the similar results.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But, comparing `int` and `const char *s` does not work the same way. "123" and "123.00" are not equal when compared using `strcmp` but are equal when compared using `numcmp`.

Comment: @BipulRanjan AFAIK, `atoi` is only for `int`s anyway. For decimals, use `atof` instead.